# Could not stablish secure channel for SSL/TLS adding new service reference in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, soap

This is the situation: New project (console or forms). I go to References, add new service reference. I write the url and I get an error about that the request is cancelled due to that it can't be stablished a secure channel for SSL/TLS. Without https, it works.
A friend tested in other windows 10 and no problem.
With Iexplorer or chrome, no problem, I see the xml of the wdsl, but with visual studio impossible, it doesn't work. I've tested all the posts that I've seen but nothing. The only way is to generate the proxy class with wdsl.exe

Any idea about this?
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you fail to invoke the wcf service by adding the service reference when the service is hosted over https?
If the server uses the self-signed certificate as the server identity credential, there is a default step validates the server certificate on the client side. you could refer to the following code.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
try
{
    var result = client.SayHello();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Hello Abraham. The problem is not to invoke the call, is to add the service. I can't add the service to Connected services (service reference).

Comment: I would like you could share the error details with me. How do you host the service and set up the authentication security to authenticate the client? I suggest you try to enable Anonymous authentication which located in the IIS authentication module when you host the service on IIS.

Comment: I'm not hosting anything. I'm only consuming a service. Details: I create a new project. I go to project references, add new service reference. In the new window, I write the service wsdl url, which is https, and VS says my request is cancelled because of it can be created a secure channel.

Comment: you could access service https wsdl in browser, while could not generate the client proxy class by adding service reference?  do you have tried the svcutil.exe? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe

Comment: Right. Yes, I've generated the proxy class using wsdl.exe by now, but I would like to know why some https urls work and others not. In fact, this url is accepted in VS in other computer but not in mine.

Comment: emm, I think you have located where the problem lies. will the version of VS and OS cause the failure? try to update them.

Comment: Yes, I thought that. I've updated VS but same result. I don't know from where VS checks certificates. It's strange because usually you don't have to install any certificate to add a https SOAP service.

Comment: Yes, I had never encountered this problem. there ought to be a problem in the local machine environment. wish you have good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the SSL certificate is not installed in your certificate repository.

Open the web service URL in browser.

It would prompt you to install the SSL CA to your local machine's certificate repository.

The dialog would be showing two options "Local User", "Local Machine".

You MUST select "Local Machine".

Then you should be able to add service reference even using SSL url.

This should solve your issues.

Comment: Thanks Manoj. When I open the URL in Chrome for example, I can see the xml but it doesn't ask me about SSL CA. It seems to be ok. I've clicked on the padlock, downloaded the certificate and installed it in Local Machine container, in Personal, root entities and intermediate entities, but nothing, I have the same problem. The browser never prompted me to install any certificate. It worked always.

Comment: Manoj, other test: The url that I'm testing is from a courier company. As I'm developing expeditions with several companies, I've tested other URL from other courier. I've opened the url in browser and no problem, I see the xml. After, I've gone to my project, added the new service reference (https too) and no problem at all, so the problem is with the first url only. The message from visual studio says: cancelled request. Can't create a secure channel ssl/tls. Metadata contains a reference that can't be resolved.

Comment: Now I'm testing with SoapUI and no problem, I can see wsdl definition, etc. The problem is only with Visual Studio.